# "ionic start" stops after downloading

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to start with Ionic using, `ionic start tabs` command. It downloaded the project and created the directory named `tabs`, but it is stopping there. There is no further progress after that.

[image: ionic start command]

`ionic info` shows the following details,

[image: ionic info]

Edit: `ionic platform add android` also shows the same response.

[image]

Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what response are you expecting from the command?

Comment: It has to download and should create a ionic project, whereas the second part is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix this issue myself. It is due to Oracle 9 which is an unstable version right now.

You may also get "`Error: Cannot read property '1' of null`" when you run the command `ionic build android`, so the solution is remove Oracle 9 and install Oracle 8 by using the following tutorial,

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html